# tkinter canvas won't update object's color after click on the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a project which kind of basic paint in python and I'm stuck on this flood fill part, it won't update the color of the object and there's no error so I can't figure out which part is wrong.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

coords = {"x1":0,"y1":0,"x2":0,"y2":0}
lines = []

class Filling():
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        self.main.title('Filling')
        self.main.geometry("800x620")
        btncir=Button(main, text="CIRCLE", fg='black', width=8, command=self.circle)
        btncir.place(x=10, y=200)
        btnfill=Button(main, text="FILL", fg='black', width=8, command=self.clickfillrec)
        btnfill.place(x=10, y=250)
        btnclear=Button(main, text="COLOR", fg='black', width=8, command=self.color_choice)
        btnclear.place(x=10, y=300)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.main, bg='white', bd=5, relief=RIDGE, height=600, width=700)
        self.canvas.place(x=80, y=0)
    def circle(self):
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.circle_click)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag) 
    def circle_click(self, e):
        coords["x1"] = e.x
        coords["y1"] = e.y
        lines.append(self.canvas.create_oval(coords["x1"],coords["y1"],coords["x1"],coords["y1"]))    
    def drag(self, e):
        coords["x2"] = e.x
        coords["y2"] = e.y
        self.canvas.coords(lines[-1], coords["x1"],coords["y1"],coords["x2"],coords["y2"])
    def color_choice(self):
        self.DEFAULT_COLOR = self.color
        self.color = askcolor()
    def clickfillrec(self):
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.ffillrec)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.nothing) 
    def nothing(self, event):
        pass
    def ffillrec(self, event):
        item = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        current_color = self.canvas.itemcget(item, 'fill')
        if (x > 0) and (self.canvas.itemcget((event.x-1, event.y), 'fill')) == current_color:
            self.canvas.itemconfig((event.x-1, event.y), fill = self.color)
        if (y > 0) and (self.canvas.itemcget((event.x, event.y-1), 'fill')) == current_color : 
            self.canvas.itemconfig((event.x, event.y-1), fill = self.color)
        if (x < self.canvas.winfo_screenwidth()) and (self.canvas.itemcget((event.x+1, event.y), 'fill')) == current_color : 
            self.canvas.itemconfig((event.x+1, event.y), fill = self.color)
        if (y < self.canvas.winfo_screenheight()) and (self.canvas.itemcget((event.x, event.y+1), 'fill')) == current_color : 
            self.canvas.itemconfig((event.x, event.y+1), fill = self.color)
main = Tk()
p = Filling(main)
main.mainloop()
```

I tried `main.update()` and `self.canvas.update_idletasks()` but still doesn't work

Comment: first declare and assign `self.color="balck"` inside the `__init__()` . now `self.color = askcolor()` ->  `self.color = askcolor()[1]`. I also believe that you don't need `if else` statements under `ffillrec` method instead  `self.canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=self.color)` should do the job.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `x` and `y` are what you think they are? Have you verified that `(event.x-1, event.y)` refers to the element you think it does? Have you verified that the correct `if` condition is being executed and that `self.color` is what you are assuming it is?